# Are there any known lower bounds on $xP(X>x)$ when $E(X) =\infty$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, reference-request, stochastic-analysis, reference-works

I have encountered following problem while I was working on something. For what follows, let $X$ be a non-negative random variable.

If we know $E(X^p)\leq \infty$, then it is well known that $x^pP(X>x) \to 0$ as $x\to \infty$. This also implies that $x^pP(X>x)$ is a bounded function in $x$.

Now, if we know $E(X) = \infty$, then are there any known lower bounds on $xP(X>x)$ under some "nice" assumptions ? (for example, X having a positive density on $[0,\infty)$ ).

For example, if $X$ has some mass at $\infty$, say $P(X= \infty) = p$, then $xP(X>x) \geq xp$ for all $x \geq 0$.

Comment: It is possible that $xP(X>x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$ but $E[X]=\infty$, even $X$ is real-valed.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X:\Omega\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ be a random variable. Let $p\in[1,\infty)$.
We recall that we have the Robin's identity
$$
E\left[X^{p}\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty}px^{p-1}P\left(X>x\right)dx.
$$
For our case, in particular, we have that $\infty=E\left[X\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left(X>x\right)dx$.
Denote $f(x)=P\left(X>x\right)$. Since $X$ is real-valued, we have
that $f(x)\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. We consider functions
of the form $g:[2,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$, $g$ is decreasing
and $\int_{2}^{\infty}g(x)dx=\infty$. Clearly, $g$ cannot decrease
too fast, e.g., $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ does not fit our criterion.
A typical example is $g_{1}(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. For this example, we
have that $xg_{1}(x)=1$. Another example is $g_{2}(x)=\frac{1}{x\ln x}$.
For this example, we have $xg_{2}(x)\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.
However, it is easy to see that $\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\ln x}dx=\infty$.

Put it formally, we argue that: There exists a random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow[0,\infty)$
such that $xP\left(X\geq x\right)\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$,
but $E\left[X\right]=\infty$.

Proof: Choose a sufficiently large $x_{0}>0.$ Define $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[0,1]$
by
$$
F(x)=\begin{cases}
1-\frac{1}{x\ln x}, & \mbox{if }x\geq x_{0}\\
0, & \mbox{if }x<x_{0}
\end{cases}.
$$
Clearly, $F$ is increasing, right-continuous, $F(x)\rightarrow1$
as $x\rightarrow\infty$, $F(x)\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow-\infty$.
Therefore, $F$ is a c.d.f.. By Skorokhod Theorem, we can construct
a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and a random variable
$X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $F(x)=P\left(X\leq x\right)$.
Clearly, $X$ is non-negative because $P(X\leq0)=F(0)=0$. Also $P(X>x)=1-F(x)=\frac{1}{x\ln x}$
for $x\geq x_{0}$. It follows that $E\left[X\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(X>x)dx\geq\int_{x_{0}}^{\infty}P(X>x)dx=\int_{x_{0}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\ln x}dx=\infty$.
Moreover, $xP(X>x)\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.